# How to show what a method returns in my application

Tags: javafx

I have a method called "showWorkers" that will show all the workers in my company, with the name, when they started working and their cargo but I'm kinda new to JavaFX and I've been looking on videos and stuff and nothing is working. I want to create a button that when it is pressed, goes to another stage and shows all the information.

```
**JAVAFX**
btnshowWorkers.setText("Mostrar Conjunto de Fichas"); // create button
btnshowWorkers.setLayoutX(10); // localização do botão btnshowWorkers.setLayoutY(250); // localização do botão btnshowWorkers.setPrefWidth(150); // localização do botão  relativamente ao comprimento
btnshowWorkers.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){            
   @Override
   public void handle(ActionEvent event){

   Stage newWindow2 = new Stage(); // cria nova variavel do tipo stage
   primaryStage.hide(); // esconde o menu principal
   VBox painelList = new VBox(); // cria nova variavel do tipo VBox
   Button btnSee=new Button(); // cria novo botão 
   Button btnExit=new Button(); // cria novo botão 
   Text erro = new Text(); // cria um variavel do tipo text
   erro.setLayoutX(193); // localização da variavel tipo text
   erro.setLayoutY(120); // localização da variavel tipo text

   company.showWorkers();

**JAVA**
 public void showWorkers() 
    {
        int n_empregdos = 0;
        for(Empregado e: worker)
        {
            System.out.println("ID : " +e.getId());
            System.out.println("Nome : " +e.getName());
            System.out.println("Data de entrada : " +e.getDataEntrada());
            System.out.println("Dias de Trabalho: " + e.workDays);
            System.out.println("Cargo : " +e.getCargo());
            n_empregdos += 1;
        }

        if(n_empregdos == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Não existem empregados inseridos!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like a `TableView` is what you want to look into. As for this question, it's far too broad for StackOverflow. Give it a shot and learn how to use a `TableView`. Then, if you run into a specific problem, head back here, search for similar questions, and we'll be happy to help if you're still stuck.

Comment: Please create minimal code in english for other users to understand instead of spanish